# Pass an object from API resource Method to APIFilter PostCheckMethod

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a use case in that for all PUT/Delete/Update call i want to send some object to PostCheck of ApiFilter for some processing.

I am trying like this :

```
@Context
HttpServletRequest request;
@Context
ContainerResponseContext responseContext ;
@PUT
@Path("/snmp")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Timed

public Response<List<SNMPSettingsFactory.ExternalSNMPSettings>> updateSNMPTargetSettingsList(
        @Nonnull SNMPSettingsFactory.ExternalSNMPSettings externalSNMPSettings)
   {
     request.setAttribute("old",oldSettingObject);
     request.setAttribute("new",currentSettingObject);
```

}

in the ApiFilter class, I am trying to get this but it is coming as NULL.

```
@Provider
public class ApiFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, 
ContainerResponseFilter {

private final ApiNonFunctionalHandler handler;
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiFilter.class);
public ApiFilter(ApiNonFunctionalHandler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

@Context
HttpServletRequest request;
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    try {
        String urlPath = requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri().getPath();
        if (!urlPath.startsWith(ApiConstants.BASE_URL)) {
            return;
        }
        UserInfo userInfo;
        String authorization = NullOrEmpty.isFalse(requestContext.getHeaderString(CspClient.AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER))?
                requestContext.getHeaderString(CspClient.AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER) : requestContext.getHeaderString("Authorization");
        userInfo = handler.preCheck(ApiUtils.getApiCategory(urlPath),
                authorization, isAuthRequired(urlPath, requestContext.getMethod()));
        requestContext.setSecurityContext(new CustomSecurityContext(userInfo,""));


    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws
        IOException {

    String urlPath = requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri().getPath();

    String callerIpAddress = null;
    if (request != null) {
        callerIpAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }

    String callerUserName = null;
    if (request != null) {
        callerUserName = request.getRemoteUser();
    }

    Object oldObject = request.getAttribute("old");
    Object currentObject = request.getAttribute("new");
```

Please help me how can I pass objects for all API call to postfilter to do some common processing like finding diff and log it.

Comment: You could inject ContainerRequestContext into the resource and use `setProperty()`. The retrieve it with `getProperty()`. You're already doing something similar with `HttpServletRequest#setAttribute()`. You could just retrieve it with `getAttribute()`

Comment: When i getting it with getAttribute() its coming as null

Comment: What's null? Are you agreeing a NullPointerException? is the HttpServletRequst null?